# How to atribute multiple values to an array from a command substitution?

Tags: shell, command-substitution

Consider the following shell script function:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a dir

function() {
local -a directories=( "A/B/C D" "E/F G H" ) #Initialize local array.
printf "%q " "${directories[@]}"             #"Return" values of array in escaped form.
}

dir=( $(funcion) )

for i in "${dir[@]}"; do
  echo $i
done
```

How I would the command substitution works:

```
dir=( A/B/C\ D E/F\ G\ H ) #Escape the whitespace.
```

The result of script shuld is:

```
A/B/C D
E/F G H
```

How the command substitution realy works (I think, because its result):

```
dir=( A/B/C\\ D E/F\\ G\\ H ) #Escape the backslash.
```

The result of script is:

```
A/B/C\
D
E/F\
G\
H
```

Is there a way to make this works like I would?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `\n` in your `printf`. You've got this:

```bash
$ directories=( "A/B/C D" "E/F G H" )
$ printf "%q " "${directories[@]}"
```

Which effectively evaluates to this:

```bash
$ printf "%q " "A/B/C D" "E/F G H"
A/B/C\ D E/F\ G\ H
```

Which results in the for loop iterating over `A/B/C\`, `D`, `E/F\`, `G\`, and `H`.

If instead, you used `"%q\n"`, you would get this:

```bash
$ printf "%q\n" "${directories[@]}"
A/B/C\ D
E/F\ G\ H
```

You could then read the result of that (assuming it comes from `func`) into an array with this:

```bash
readarray -t dir < <(func)
```

Comment: but `readarray -t dir < <(printf "%q\n" "A/B/C D" "E/F G H")` would still invent literal backslashes in the array values, e.g. `"${dir[0]}"` would have `A/B/C\ D`. With that `readarray` you probably want just `printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"` (and note the caveat that you can't then have newlines in the values)

Comment: It works fine, but ilkkachu's comment is important, because the function of the backslash here is to escape the whitespace of path, and it is generated by `printf` with `%q`. But, why bash do not simply replace the `$(funcion)` by `A/B/C\ D E/F\ G\ H` in expansion and execute `dir=( A/B/C\ D E/F\ G\ H )`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> directories=( "A/B/C D" "E/F G H" ) #Initialize local array.
> printf "%q " "${directories[@]}"
> ```

This would print the values quoted so that the output is suitable for use as shell input.

> ```
> dir=( $(func) )
> ```

And this would get the output of `func`, run it through word-splitting and globbing, and store the resulting fields in the array.

Those are not compatible formats. In particular, the latter considers the
data it gets as *data*, it doesn't parse it for shell syntax like quotes,  escapes or operators or anything. It just looks at whitespace. (There's no escaping the backslashes in the data. They just don't have a special meaning to begin with.)

If you want to process input as shell syntax, you need to run it through `eval`, but that has the downside that anything else goes too, e.g. embedded command substitutions would run (think `$(reboot)`).

A better way is to not turn the data into shell syntax to begin with. Instead, print the array values with some suitable character as terminator and use `read` or `readarray` along with process substitution to read them back in.

E.g. with a newline separator:

```
f() {
    printf "%s\n" "hello world" 'some"quotes\etc'
}
readarray -t arr < <(f)
```

Or with the NUL character as separator, so you can have newlines in the values:

```
g() {
    printf "%s\0" "hello world" 'some"quotes\etc' $'two\nlines\n'
}
readarray -d '' -t arr < <(g)
```

(Incidentally, `function() ...` doesn't work in Bash, since `function` is a keyword there. It does work in Dash and Busybox, though, but then arrays don't.)